# Inserting parts of one 2d array into a 20x20 matrix in python

Tags: python, arrays, matrix

So I am trying to insert the word array into the 20x20 matrix. I am not sure how to write a loop that inserts each character of the list into the grid. The final outcome of this code should be a crossword puzzle.

```
def crossword(L):
  L1 = L.sort(key = len)
  L1 = L.copy()
  L1.reverse()


  matrix = [[0 for i in range(20)] for j in range(20)]

  word = [list(L1[i]) for i in range(len(L1))]

  #for i in range(len(L1)): 
  #  word = list(L1[i])

  for i in range(len(L1[0])):
    print(word[0][i])
    word[0][i] = matrix[i][0]

  for i in matrix:
    print(i)

words = ["help","hi", "interest", "total", "lame"]
crossword(words)
```

My plan is creating a descending list of the words, highest to lowest amount of characters and insert each one in the grid, both horizontally and vertically.

The outcome of the above code is:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]                                                     
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]                                                     
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]                                                     
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]                                                     
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]                                                     
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]                                                     
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]                                                     
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]                                                     
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]                                                     
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]                                                     
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]                                                     
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]                                                     
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]                                                     
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]                                                     
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]                                                     
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]                                                     
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]                                                     
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]                                                     
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]                                                     
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

This is just the empty 20x20 grid. Furthermore I don't want to use numpy, just plain vanilla python.

Comment: You want to insert the same word both horizontally and vertically?

Comment: @DanielMesejo Not the same word, whatever word that happens to work with it. Like  "help" can be inserted with hi since they share a common letter (h).

Comment: It’s not an answer to your question, but `[list(L1[i]) for i in range(len(L1))]` can be rewritten as `[list(curr_item) for curr_item in L1]`. Also, you can replace variables you don’t need with `_`, like in `[0 for i in range(20)]`. These are just small changes, it may turn out to be useless if the program as a whole is refactored (I will take a closer look tomorrow)

Comment: @AlexanderCécile Thank you! Please let me know if you have any questions. I'm just having trouble putting the characters in the grid.

Comment: @equane I’m not sure I understand what determines where each word should go. Can you expand on that?

Comment: @AlexanderCécile Each word needs to be on the grid like if its a crossword, either horizontally or vertically. If a word can not be added, we skip that word.

Furthermore when adding words to the grid, they can not create new words.

Comment: @equane "If a word can not be added, we skip that word." What do you mean by "cannot be added"?

Comment: @AlexanderCécile lets say for example the words are: STOP and HELL, they cant be added together in the crossword as they dont share a common letter.

Comment: @equane Are you looking for the entire crossword-esque logic? I assumed you just wanted to know about list indexing and assignment.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile I guess for now indexing and assignment is what I need.

Comment: @equane Would you like a general explanation of indexing with some examples, or would you rather think about the algorithm a bit further and then get more specific advice?

Comment: @AlexanderCécile A general explanation on how to actually replace elements of the 20x20 grid with the characters from each word in the list would be beneficial.